# How to import JQuery to custom dnn module

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have created custom DNN module that should use some `JQuery` plugins.
I loaded plugins fine.
But getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function imagesloaded.js?cdv=18:93
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded' Masonry:755
GET http://dnn7site/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found) Masonry:464
GET http://dnn7site/resources/shared/scripts/jquery/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

And I think that this is because `JQuery` is not imported in my custom module.
I included other `JS` files like:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"  />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js"  />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/imagesloaded.js"  />
```

But I don't know how to import `JQuery`, any help?
I am using **DNN 7.1.1**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't include jquery using the method described in the other answer. This will potentially cause conflicts with the jquery version that may be bundled with your DNN installation and/or other modules.

To include jQuery in DNN, it's as follows:

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration()
```

If you want jquery UI, use:

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestUIRegistration()
```

If you want to do it through a ASCX file, use this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="JQUERY" Src="~/Admin/Skins/jQuery.ascx" %>
<dnn:JQUERY ID="dnnjQuery" runat="server" />
```

More information can be found here:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/jQuery

The version of jquery and whether it uses a hosted file can be configured in host settings -> advanced settings -> jquery settings.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is required, try [downloading](http://jquery.com/download/) the jQuery library and placing the jQuery script file in the same location as the other script files, and ensure that the jQuery library is reference before any other script files that require jQuery.  For example:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"  />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"  />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js"  />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/imagesloaded.js"  />
```

However, the [Masonry documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started) suggests that jQuery is not required to run the plugin, so your problem may lie elsewhere

*jQuery is not required to use Masonry. But if you do enjoy jQuery, Masonry works with it as a jQuery plugin.*

Comment: Yes but masonry is no the only plugin in module other requires jquery to work. But JQuery is not in my mobule folder it's in DNN. And I need to use DNN default JQuery just don't know how to import it.

Comment: What's the path the jQuery library?